# Magento 2 - Redirect base url to base url with store code

Tags: magento2, multistore, redirect

In Magento 2 I have two stores with "add store code in url" option enable.

Store code 1 = "fr"

Store code 2 = "es"

I want to automatically add default store code in url:

Redirect http://mywebsite.com to http://mywebsite.com/fr/

Actually when I visit http://mywebsite.com I stay to this url and default store code is not added automatically.

Do you know how to change that ?
Is there a Magento 2 option for that ? Or should I write condition in .htaccess file ?

---

**Solution :**

I add this rule in my .htaccess file to solve this issue :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /fr/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Navigate to Stores > Configuration > General > Web and find the Url Options section. There you choose to Add Store Code to URLs selecting Yes from the corresponding select box and Save Config

Comment: @Mehran yes this option is already enable, I mentioned it in my post

Comment: @Mehran My problem is when I visit url without store code, store code is not automatically added to the url.
But when I visit url with store code it's OK

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to go store->configuration->select the scope(select store) and On the left panel, under General, select Web-> Base URL like this http://127.0.0.1/magento2/pub/fr/ or http://127.0.0.1/magento2/pub/es/. http://127.0.0.1/magento2/pub/ is the default base url

Comment: Thanks but it's not working because it duplicate store code in url : http://mywebsite.com/fr/fr/
My problem is when I visit url without store code, store code is not automatically added to the url. But when I visit url with store code it's OK

Comment: how you solved this problem??I'm also facing this issue

Comment: @aich.khalid check my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. Specify in your env.php file the data you want applied and run bin/magento  setup:upgrade in terminal.
2. SSH into your server and run this bin/magento command:

   bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://<your_url>" --base-url-secure="https://<your_url>" --use-secure=0 --use-secure-admin=0
3. Set your config values in the core_config_data table of your database. In phpmyadmin, run this sql: and edit as you see fit per scope:

   SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path like '%web%'

Answer (score 0):

I just did it and here is my solution:

First, go to `Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Base URLs`

And please do all the following exactly step by step:

1. Change `Base URL` to http://mywebsite.com/fr/
2. For `Base Link URL` Uncheck `Use system value` and keep the value http://mywebsite.com/
3. Change `Base URL for Static View Files` to http://mywebsite.com/static/
4. Change `Base URL for User Media Files` to http://mywebsite.com/media/

Now your website will be working for the default store view

**Caution:** Other store views now won't be working, fortunately, we can fix it.

5. Switch the configuration scope for every store view and change the `Base URL` to [http://mywebsite.com/[store_code]/](http://mywebsite.com/%5Bstore_code%5D/)

Cheers, now your website is working as desired.